# Almacenar binarios en un Array - Java

Tags: java

Estoy trabajando en este conversor de binarios a decimales y viceversa y necesito que cada numero del binario quede guardado en una posición de un *array*, lo mismo para los decimales alguna idea este es el código.

```
package numerosBinariosYDecimales;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BinariosYDecimales {
    public static void main (String[]args){


        Scanner lecturaDatos = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingresa un numero decimal");
        long decimal =lecturaDatos.nextLong();
        long auxiliar = decimal;
        String binario="";

        while (auxiliar >0){
            binario = auxiliar %2 + binario;
            auxiliar /=2;

        }
        System.out.println("El numero decimal "+decimal+" en binario es: "+binario);

        //conversion de binario a decimal

        long numBinario = Long.parseLong(binario);
        long numDecimal=0;
        int contador =1;
        long auxiliarDecimal;
        while (numBinario >0){
            auxiliarDecimal = numBinario %2;
            numDecimal = numDecimal + auxiliarDecimal * contador;
            numBinario /=10;
            contador = contador*2;

        }
        System.out.println("El numero binario "+binario+" es "+decimal+" en numeros decimales");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que te refieres a algo así:

```
public class BinariosYDecimales {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numeroDeNumeros = 0;

    Scanner lecturaDatos = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingresa el numero de numeros a convertir");
    numeroDeNumeros = lecturaDatos.nextInt();
    String[] matrizBinaria = new String[numeroDeNumeros];
    long[] matrizDecimal = new long[numeroDeNumeros];

    for (int i = 0; i < numeroDeNumeros; i++) {
        System.out.println("Ingresa un numero decimal");
        long decimal = lecturaDatos.nextLong();
        long auxiliar = decimal;
        String binario = "";

        while (auxiliar > 0) {
            binario = auxiliar % 2 + binario;
            auxiliar /= 2;
            matrizBinaria[i] = binario;

        }
        System.out.println("El numero decimal " + decimal + " en binario es: " + binario);

        // conversion de binario a decimal

        long numBinario = Long.parseLong(binario);
        long numDecimal = 0;
        int contador = 1;
        long auxiliarDecimal;
        while (numBinario > 0) {
            auxiliarDecimal = numBinario % 2;
            numDecimal = numDecimal + auxiliarDecimal * contador;
            numBinario /= 10;
            contador = contador * 2;
            matrizDecimal[i] = decimal;

        }
        System.out.println("El numero binario " + binario + " es " + decimal + " en numeros decimales");

    }
    // Prueba impresión matrices
    System.out.println("PRUEBA VISUALIZACION MATRICES");
    for (int i = 0; i < numeroDeNumeros; i++) {
        System.out.print(matrizBinaria[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < numeroDeNumeros; i++) {
        System.out.print(matrizDecimal[i] + " ");
    }
}

}
```

Como puedes ver he creado auxiliares para saber el numero de veces que hay que pedir números por pantalla.
El resto era simplemente crear los arrays e iterar.
Realmente lo que deberías hacer es un método añadir binariosDecimales y en el main introducir los elementos del array. Aún así creo que esto responde a tu pregunta.